# Unable to run Python Script from PHP and print output to browser

Tags: php, python, amazon-web-services

I've seen a lot of other people running into a similar problem where they can't run Python scripts from PHP. I'm having the same situation, but I have tried all of the solutions that people recommended, but still no luck. I also have a fresh system install and have made my scripts as simple as possible. Regardless of what I do, shell_exec() returns NULL.

So here is how to replicate my issue:

1. Boot up a t2.micro EC2 server on Amazon AWS
2. Configure it as a web server ([instructions here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Tutorials.WebServerDB.CreateWebServer.html))
3. Upload an index.php file to /var/www/html with the following code:

---

```
<?php 
$command = escapeshellcmd('sudo /usr/bin/python '.__DIR__.'/script.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
exit(var_dump($output));
```

4. Upload a script.py file to the same directory with the following code:

---

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print('Hello!')
```

5. Go to the AWS public URL. The response you will get is "NULL"

So to try to solve this issue, I also changed the user group of the .py file to "apache" and I ran chmod +x on the .py file. I confirmed that ec2-user AND apache are in the sudo group. Still no luck! So what haven't I tried? What am I missing or where can I go looking for error logs?

Comment: Do you have the web user setup in sudoers?

Comment: Just tested and ec2-user is a sudoer and no password is requested when you use the sudo command

Comment: I also went ahead and added apache to the sudoers list as well just in case.

Comment: Nevermind, you were right, Devon! I also needed to restart my server after adding the apache to the sudo group and then it worked. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah, be very careful having apache as a sudoer.  Anyone who exploits the web server, or any web script could then do anything on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Using the file constant `__FILE__` to determine the path to your pyhton script only works, if you apply the `dirname` function to it - otherwhise you would get something like `/var/www/html/script.php/script.py`, but you actually want only `/var/www/html/script.py`.

There are two simple solutions. Use `dirname` or directly the `__DIR__` constant.

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('sudo /usr/bin/python ' . __DIR__ . '/script.py');
```

or

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('sudo /usr/bin/python ' . dirname(__FILE__) . '/script.py');
```

Comment: Tried it, still no luck :/ But you were totally right about the __FILE__ not working so thanks for that!

Comment: Btw. need your Python script really root permissions? Sudo normally need the sudo users password as input

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. I was having no luck running the python script without sudo permission and then, once I added the apache user to the sudo group, it started working.

Comment: if you honestly not sure, use `escapeshellcmd('/usr/bin/python '.__DIR__.'/script.py');` and fix the file/folder permissions. It's a very bad idea to give apache root permissions

Comment: Ok so I couldn't get the python script to run not as a sudo user. However, it turned out my full script needed python3 to run. For some reason, python3 does not require sudo to run (maybe because I installed python3 as my user? So I was able to remove apache from the sudo user group and run the script with python3.